# Is there any reason against changing the starredness of a command upon redefinition?

Tags: macros, starred-version

If an original definition of a command used `\newcommand`, is there an obligation for me to redefine it with `\renewcommand` instead of `\renewcommand*`?

If an original definition of a command used `\newcommand*`, is there an obligation for me to redefine it with `\renewcommand*` instead of `\renewcommand`?

Note that I am **not** asking about replacing a command `\somecommand` by `\somecommand*` or vice-versa (which is incidentally tricky and also amounts to adding a command with a technically different name). I am instead asking about whether the subtle changes in semantics of `\somecommand` effected by the `*` in the command's redefinition are a syntactic (or other type of) problem for LaTeX.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is "no", but it doesn't hurt to verify. I don't know how commands are processed internally.

Comment: I think the only possible issue is for a case where the original definition was `\newcommand` as that would allow a `\par` in the input, but with the redefinition using `\renewcommand*` you no longer allow that, so perhaps some portion of the input the was working before will now fail.  I normally try to match the previous definition as there should be a reason to decide to chose the `*` or non `*` version.

Comment: @PeterGrill That would mean the answer is "no": the reason for using a `*` in your example would be the semantics/content of the command, not an underlying (La)TeX constraint (such as some internal flag in a hash table being permanently set).

Comment: Yes, but if you are redefining something that is used in other packages you could possible break things by adding a `*` to something that was originally defined without a `*`.  I don't think there are any checks to ensure that the number of parameters or types at all match the initial definition. The only check is if the macro already exists or not (hence the value of `\renewcommand`). Similar to the value of `\newcommand` to ensure that the macro did not already exist.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would claim that your concern can be subsumed by the "semantics" category. But your points that (1) one needs to watch out for usage in other packages and (2) that there exist no checks for a changed number of arguments upon a command's redefinition are very good.

Comment: @PeterGrill In your first comment you wrote "I normally try to match the previous definition". I do this too, but ... am I correct that there is **no** reason to match the previous definition if the original version was a 0-argument command?

Comment: I just can't see why it would matter for a zero parameter macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case outlined in the question, a macro that is 'short' is redefined to be 'long':

```
\newcommand*{\foo}...

 ...

\renewcommand{\foo}... % Now 'long'
```

If we assume that the fundamental meaning of `\foo` is not being altered, then anything which was valid as input for the original version is still valid with the new one. The old `\foo` did not accept `\par`, so with no change in semantics the new `\foo` should not get any `\par` tokens and the fact that it's now long will not make a difference. Of course, it does mean that we can't rely on TeX spotting a missing `}` or whatever.

A change the other way around:

```
\newcommand{\foo}...

 ...

\renewcommand*{\foo}... % Not 'long' any more
```

may of course lead to an issue if `\foo` can logically take `\par` tokens in arguments.

One thing to watch here is that even with identical definitions, long and short macros are not 'equivalent', even if there are no arguments. Thus

```
\newcommand{\fooa}{Some stuff}
\newcommand*{\foob}{Some stuff}
\ifx\fooa\foob
  TRUE
\else
  FALSE
\fi
```

gives `FALSE`. As a result, if any other code wants to test the definition of `\foo` and you've altered it from 'short' to 'long', the test will fail quite apart from any change in the actual code. For that reason alone, I'd tend to maintain the 'long' status of any macro I redefine.

Comment: The last point comes up when macros are used as storage variables: there are some in the font system in the LaTeX kernel that are long for some reason, and so you have to test against long macros.

Comment: One minor informational addendum: If I do `\renewcommand[*]{\somecommand}...` with a starredness different from before, it is probably the case that my new definition contains original content in a way that it's nearly always different from anything else stored in (La)TeX's table of commands. So, this is usually not a practical problem when I've personally authored the new definition body. // In any event, your "One thing to watch" paragraph has exactly the type of detail I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, an elaboration of Joseph Wright's point about fonts is found in user egreg's answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97645#97672).